# Index signature for type 'string' is missing

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to type my data in Firebase Cloud Functions using Typescript:

```
type SpotPriceByDay = {
  NOK_per_kWh: number;
  valid_from: string;
  valid_to: string;
}
type SpotPrices = {
  [date: string]: SpotPriceByDay
}
```

My Typescript compiler gives me an error when trying to use this

```
let data: SpotPrices = response.data;
data = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  const newKey = new Date(key).toISOString();
  return {[newKey]: data[key]};
});
```

```
error TS2322: Type '{ [x: string]: SpotPriceByDay; }[]' is not assignable to type 'SpotPrices'.
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: SpotPriceByDay; }[]'.
```

I have tried to understand how I can fix this error, but I have no clue. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a ***map*** of type `SpotPrices` but the map function here returns an ***array*** of SpotPrices objects. Assigning the result of the map should be a way to resolve this:

```
const data: SpotPrices = response.data;

const parsedData = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  const newKey = new Date(key).toISOString();
  return { [newKey]: data[key] };
});
```

Another way would be changing type of data to either `SpotPrices` or `SpotPrices[]`:

```
let data: SpotPrices | SpotPrices[] = response.data;

data = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  const newKey = new Date(key).toISOString();
  return { [newKey]: (data as SpotPrices)[key] };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I was temporarily turning it into an array to change the keys. In the next line I changed it back: `data = dataArr.reduce((a: SpotPrices, b: SpotPrices) => Object.assign({}, a, b));`